# Listen field's event within roweditor

Tags: extjs4.1, extjs-mvc

I'm well aware about how to listen event on roweditor on a controller, which is by using control config to query grid with roweditor plugin inside then fire roweditor event.. **but the exact event I want to listen to is actually belongs to the component (textfield, for instance) within that roweditor**. I don't think that event relayed to the grid panel.

Is there a way to actually listen field's event within that roweditor by using controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I somehow managed to succesfully listen event from components within grid roweditor. It's turn out we can not query that components as children of the grid.

Suppose I want to get field component within grid roweditor, this code will return null

```
Ext.ComponentQuery.query('grid field[id=test]');
```

instead, query that field as it was not the child of that grid and it works

```
Ext.ComponentQuery.query('field[id=test]');
```

Comment: Having wasted several hours on this, i have also realized that its not straightforward to listen to events from editor fields. This [sencha post](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?263232-Controller-grid-editor-change-event)  sheds some light on it.